# Android : Intercept network calls (HTTP, HTTPS etc..) originated from 3rd party libraries inside my App

Tags: android, security, http, proxy, network-programming

I saw some SO post (Some are new and some old) related to this and couldn't find relevant answer. Is it possible to intercept HTTP calls originated from 3rd party libraries and block them from within the app? Basically I wanted to make sure in my app about what HTTP calls are going out through it. Since I am using third party libraries I wanted to profile it for all the HTTP calls and then black list any unnecessary calls made by third party libraries. I am aware that the 3rd party library is making HTTP calls to handle its feature. I wanted to stop it sending any data from my App. I know I can use HTTP debugging proxy apps like Charles to know what calls are going through my app and then decide whether to use the library or not. But I wanted to use the library by just blocking only some unnecessary calls.

Comment: Not really. With Android 7.0's network security configuration, you could perhaps hack something together, whitelisting your own domain (with appropriate SSL rules), and saying that everything else does not allow system certificates or cleartext traffic (which probably will break the libraries). Even that won't work for native code, `WebView`, and perhaps some low-level Java socket work.

Comment: Thanks! for pointing me to Network Security Configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Create custom URLStreamHandlerFactory and URLStreamHandler and set it from application onCreate() by calling URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(this) it will allow to capture/block all network traffic even made by third party library.